# class design for this game(java)

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm a programming fan and want to make a Java program for automation of my City game (real game with small toy car that i play with my brother). It's 100% not homework or school problem.

I have made a `Citizen` class and a `Jobs` class. Each job has got a name, base income, income multiplier (for job ranks).

I want to make objects for each job, and connect each citizen to it but i have these problems:

1. If two people have got the same job, two job object is created (i want to be just one);
2. I don't know whether i should make classes for each job separately (sub class) or create one new job object if a player has a new job when i'm initializing a new citizen.

Comment: Just instantiate job object once and refer it to the Citizen object.

Comment: Perhaps if you post some code you would find the answers more helpful.

Comment: How and when does your game use multipliers? That will determine where to place them. Are they the same set (1x, 1.1x, 1.5x) across each job with the ranks renamed (that is, apprentice-journeyman-master plumber and (police recruit-sergeant-chief) use the same multiples atop the Plumber and Police salaries? Even if it's just profession-specific, might Mario negotiate for a better raise at Master Plumber level than Luigi could?

Comment: for example teacher have base 100 multiplier 1.5 and police has base 600  multiplier of 1.1 which means teacher income increases faster by rank than police(not linear, i have a special formula)

Comment: Hmm... Then in that case, place the multiplier in the Job class, since it follows the job type. When you create the Teacher job set multiplier 1.5, and create Police with multiplier 1.1. Don't put your whole formula in each job. Have some other class read the multiplier and apply the formula. If we haven't said it already, welcome to Stack Overflow! The format here is a little different than forums. Edit all of your clarification back into the original question. You'll get rep for it! Ask another question about byte and float math. Also, try to wait about 24 hours before "accepting" an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if two people have got the same job, two job object is created (i want to be just one)

Two main options:

1. Make each job instance a `Singleton` (if you don't know what a singleton is, just google it or search here on SO).
2. Make a singleton `Job Manager` class that holds a `Set` (or `Map` or `List`, but you probably want a `Set`), pairing job names to an instance of that job's class; which you can then simply get a reference to, instead of creating a new one.

---

> i don't know whether i should make classes for each job separately (sub class) or create one new job object if a player has a new job when i'm initializing a new citizen.

You probably shouldn't. Instead, make the things common to all jobs an `abstract` parent class, and then implement each job class as extensions to that. If, however you just need the variables within the `Job` class to contain different values for each individual job, you want multiple `instances` of your single Job class, each with their own set of values. For example:

```
class Job{
  public String name;
  public float salary;
  public float multiplier;

  public Job(String name, float salary, float multiplier){
    this.name=name;
    this.salary=salary;
    this.multiplier=multiplier;
  }
}

//On Main
Job banker = new Job("Banker", 9000, 1);
Job seniorBanker = new Job("Senior Banker", 9000, 1.2f);
Job plumber = new Job("Plumber", 800, 1);

//...
//Assuming citizen class contains Job variable: public Job job;
Citizen jack = new Citizen(); 
jack.job = banker;
Citizen mario = new Citizen(); 
mario.job = plumber;
Citizen luigi = new Citizen(); 
luigi.job = plumber; //Same instance of 'plumber' as mario's...
//If you change the value of the plumber's job salary, and then do...
  //system.out.println(mario.job.salary);
  //system.out.println(luigi.job.salary);
//...both will be changed.
```

Note: As you can see above, your current design (from what can be inferred) doesn't reuse data from previous job tiers, making the `multiplier` redundant and kinda pointless.
A better design would be to have the ranks built into the job class as a `Map`, pairing tiers to specific names and multipliers.

Note of acknowledgement: This is basically going to turn the `Job` class into the equivalent of a `Profession` class, which is what garnulf suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39298650/1253136).

Comment: thanks for help, all jobs have same variables and different amount(all have only name,base income, and rank multiplier but different valuse for each job)(functions like a job database)and i want to connect each citizen with it job) what should i do?

Comment: Maybe my initial example didn't make it clear enough how to pair citizens to instances of jobs...I edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: thank for the code, your code seems great but what i have in mind is: someone is banker and is level one, as he gets to higher level his income increases by specific formula that i have in mind, job class is just a reference for citizen to know base income and multiplier of a job. as i searched Singleton is ok. i just dont know how i should connect citizen to job and be able to change its job later

Comment: nice, your new code looks great. is there a way so i can assign players job with scanner?

Comment: @Nemexia "is there a way so i can assign players job with scanner" you're getting out of the scope of this question there... The short answer is: Yes. As for how to, please search previous questions about it here on SO. =)

Comment: just one more thing, my rank is in byte format and income is in float so i cant do math with them together should i make rank float or there is some conversion code available.

Comment: @Nemexia Is there any specific reason to use byte? If not, use int. And also, is income always a whole number? If yes, again, int. If you're worried about performance or size, then you're probably engaging in *premature optimization*, and, specially as you're new to coding, my advice is: Don't be. Generally, optimizations should only be done when they need to. --- Oh, and as for conversions, when you actually need them, in Java they're generally done with *casting* (google it)

Comment: thank found casting, everything is fine except how to do jack.job=banker part(giving jobs to people) with scanner. Thanks for help everyone!

Comment: found it too yay!

Comment: @Nemexia It isn't clear if you're using the `Scanner` for file IO or as a console (`System.in`), but you generally use scanners to read or write individual *fields* (values). As for your last comment, you seem to have found a solution; it would be a nice to post the source-code here as answer, along with explanations of what you have done; that way, other people with the same problem will have an even easier time understanding the solution, and people with more coding experience can help improve the code through suggestions and feedback. =)

Comment: @Nemexia It's important to note, however, that here on SO the primary purpose of posting source-code in such manner is for other people with similar problems to be able to understand how to resolve the issues they are having, and not for review/feedback. --- When you need code-review without having any specific problem (or when the problem has already been asked about by someone else), there is another (aptly named) StackExchange website for that: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) --- =)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Citizen{
    String name;
         .
         .
         .
    Job job; 
}


class Job{
   // all fields you need
}
```

Now just instantiate Job object with different parameters once and then when you create Citizen objects just use the job variable(in Citizen class) to reference the Job object. So multiple citizen objects could refer to the same Job object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should distinguish between a `Job` and a `Profession`. Each `Citizen` should have his/her own `Job` because the `salary` and `employer` is indvidual for example. But each `Job` is also associated to a `Profession` which then is the same `Object` for different `Citizen` sharing the same `Profession`. It could be a good idea to use an `enum` for the `Profession`, this way you enforce that there is only one `Object` for each `Profession`.

Comment: If everyone with the same `Job` has the same salary he can obviously just go with an `enum` `Job`, maybe this is good enough for him. He mentioned the salary in OP though, so it should be a lot more realistic to have individual salaries.

Comment: I didn't mean it as saying this is a bad solution. It isn't. I'm saying this is going to introduce too many new concepts to the OP, which clearly is new to coding, and probably just get him even more confused.

Comment: @AlmightyR How is this inflating OP's problem? Separating the role from the individual instance is logical OOP. Your solution also makes sense and doesn't form bad habits, but also introduces many new and confusing concepts. An Enum would achieve both the Singleton and "job database" solutions. Put a member in the enum which is a collection of citizens, and it's complete.

Comment: @newcoder "Put a member in the enum" - Try to explain that to someone who doesn't even understand how to do `citizen.job=job`... Your mistake is in "is logical OOP"; I agree garnulf's solution is a good one...for us who are experienced. The OP isn't. This is why my solution only uses what the OP is most familiar with, and the utmost basic: classes, variables and references. (and as you can see, even at that he's not all that familiar)...

Comment: @AlmightyR important distinction. Thank you. This reminds me of the infamous Duck Simulator example, where one must first build it to work, then quickly learn to refactor to keep it working. It's hard for the experienced to remember what it is like to be on the sharp end of that initial learning curve. You seem to have done a great job of setting the OP on the right track for them... Which wouldn't have gotten me un-stuck at that point in learning, but I'm an OddDuck.